# Online Multiplayer Game development

Tags: web-development, web-server, game-development

I am planning to develop an online multiplayer game with the following features

- An interface through which players can play and chat
- Players are shown a list of active players and their rankings so that they can choose their opponents
- Players can set up their boards. Once done, the game starts in which each player makes a move in their turn

This will be my first attempt at game development. I am looking for softwares/frameworks which I can use to accomplish my task with the least time spent on boilerplate code and such stuff.

Presently, I plan to use the following:

- React and Bootstrap/Materialise for the frontend GUI
- Sockets in Java / socket.io for handling the communication
- RESTful APIs for storing the scores and login data of the users on SQL database

Are these feasible? Do there exist better/easier methods to implement the above things?

Comment: Can some one please help me out with this? I don't have sufficient reputations yet to offer a bounty.

Comment: I think this is better place for this - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/